show values as multi select combobox/picklist from a apex class output
in screen flow i am using apex class to recieve related records from a record id, where i have not hardcoded any object, i can pass any object to get its related records
public with sharing class CloneRecordHelper {
@InvocableMethod
public static List<PicklistValueInfo> getRelatedObjects(List<Id> recordIds) {
    Set<String> relatedObjectNames = new Set<String>();

    for (Id recordId : recordIds) {
        String objectApiName = recordId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describeResult = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectApiName).getDescribe();
        List<Schema.ChildRelationship> childRelationships = describeResult.getChildRelationships();

        for (Schema.ChildRelationship childRel : childRelationships) {
            String childObjectName = childRel.getChildSObject().getDescribe().getName();
            String relationshipField = childRel.getField().getDescribe().getName();

            if (childRel.getRelationshipName() != null && (childRel.getField().getDescribe().getType() == Schema.DisplayType.REFERENCE)) {
                try {
                    String query = 'SELECT Id FROM ' + childObjectName + ' WHERE ' + relationshipField + ' = :recordId LIMIT 10';
                    List<SObject> relatedRecords = Database.query(query);

                    if (!relatedRecords.isEmpty()) {
                        relatedObjectNames.add(childObjectName); // Add to set for picklist
                    }
                } catch (QueryException e) {
                    System.debug('Skipping object: ' + childObjectName + ' due to query error: ' + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Convert Set to List of PicklistValueInfo
    List<PicklistValueInfo> picklistEntries = new List<PicklistValueInfo>();
    for (String objectName : relatedObjectNames) {
        picklistEntries.add(new PicklistValueInfo(objectName, objectName));
    }

    System.debug('picklistEntries: ' + picklistEntries);
    return picklistEntries;
}

public class PicklistValueInfo {
    @InvocableVariable
    public String label;
    @InvocableVariable
    public String value;

    public PicklistValueInfo(String label, String value) {
        this.label = label;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

}
here is its output
for multiple related reocrd,
DEBUG|picklistEntries: (PicklistValueInfo:[label=Account, value=Account], PicklistValueInfo:[label=Contact, value=Contact], PicklistValueInfo:[label=Opportunity, value=Opportunity])
for single related record,
DEBUG|picklistEntries: (PicklistValueInfo:[label=Contact, value=Contact])
here is my apex class, the apex class is showing reuslts correctly, the issue is that i am unable to show them on screen flow screen element. this flow is working correctly for object which have only one related object, but getting error for object which have multiple related object
i have tried it using record type variable where object is "picklistvalueinfo"(used as single varible because if i am changing it to allow collections it is not visible in output), and setting the output values in this variable.
full screen flow woking fine for record id which have single related object, but not wokring for recordid which have multiple related object,
i want to show all the result values as a multi select picklist/ combobox.
